# Windows Form Tabpage loads slowly

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, tabpage

I have a tab-control that has 4 tab pages. Each tab page contains a user-control that I add programmatically when the program first loads. For some reason the second tab-page loads slow when I click on it but the other tabs load fine. This tab-page does contain about 20 controls(text boxes, drop-downs, list boxes, etc) but no images or anything like that. Also that page has around the same number of controls as the others. Is there any way to speed up the switching of the tabs? Can I preload the tab-page at startup?

Note: It is only slow on the initial switch.

This is how I add the Usercontrol

```
tabPage2.Controls.Add(userControl_1);
        // 
        // userControl_1
        // 
        userControl_1.Anchor = ((AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                                  | AnchorStyles.Left)
                                 | AnchorStyles.Right;
        userControl_1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        userControl_1.Name = "userControl_1";
        userControl_1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(878, 646);
        userControl_1.TabIndex = 0;
```

Comment: Have you tried `userControl_1.Dock = Dockstyle.Fill' instead of all those size and anchor settings ?

Comment: Tried that but it didn't render the control correct at the bottom, also didn't fix the slowness.

Comment: It is almost *never* the 'loading' that's slow (unless databound), it is the *painting* that makes it look slow.

Comment: The Docking remark wasn't about the speed, I just don't like 878x646 controls.

Comment: @Henk, If I could change it I would but I just inherited the application didn't design it.

Comment: @Hans, I understand it's the painting and in a sense that's what I mean. I'm looking for a way to pre-render the page I guess.

Comment: That's not an option.  Find out why this particular set of controls is slow to paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the TabControl: The contents of a tab are only loaded when they are clicked for the first time.

It would therefore appear to be a problem of that UC on the 2nd Tabpage, look for the resources (queries) it uses.

Comment: Thats the thing though, I'm using Nhibernate and when I click the tab it doesn't show any queries being ran in Nhibernate Profiler.

Comment: Then look for something else that might slow it down.

Comment: I've looked for everything I can think of, thats why I'm asking on here. Theres no way to preload the tabpage that you know of?

Comment: You could try reading its handle (or the UC handle) when the form loads.

Comment: @Henk, What do you mean by reading its handle? Please explain

Comment: @Henk, I read the handles but there just numbers? Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: So I have found a solution** for now. When the form loads I just cycle through all the tab pages. Not the best solution at all but it works.

Comment: Getting the handle should/could have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` before and after loading all of the Controls.

Like so

```
UserControlName.SuspendLayout();

//Load all of the controls

UserControlName.ResumeLayout();
```

This will cause it to not draw anything until it has initialized all of the controls you are trying to load.

Comment: Yes I am actually. I commented it out but theres still some lag between when they click the tab and when it is displayed. 3-4s. Could this be a LINQ thing maybe? It shows that everything is being loaded at startup. Can LINQ delay like that?

Comment: @Gage yes, that is one of the main points of LINQ. It doesn't load anything till you actually access the data in the query